# Flutter Image displays incorrect color

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter image won't display color correctly. Any way to fix this?

I have an asset with a background mainly consisting of the color #2E4050, a blue-grey color.
Yet when I render this asset in Flutter it displays as #29434f, a dark teal color.
If I render a solid background color of #2E4050 side by side with my asset you can see a clear difference.

[image: Left: asset - right: solid color]

Minimal working example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        home: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(child: Image.network('https://i.imgur.com/o77jhZT.png')),
            Expanded(child: Container(color: const Color(0xff2E4050)))
          ],
        ),
      );
}
```

Comment: Downloaded your image... it has the color 0xff294151

Comment: Does your device have some blue light filter setting? It seems to me that might be the case, because I can in fact see that the color in your screenshot it not the same as the image itself. The colored container is also not exactly 0xff2E4050 in your screenshot

Comment: @MCB https://i.imgur.com/dHitnlx.png This is what color picker shows

Comment: @Ivo screenshot might have some compression - doesn't negate the stark difference between the solid color and image side-by-side on the device itself. Even if it has a blue filter it should appear the same on the same screen if it has the same color.

Comment: I got this https://i.stack.imgur.com/wELmQ.png

Comment: Can you clarify what device you are using? Emulators and Physical devices will always show slightly different colors. It has a lot to do with the screens themselves. Rarely will you get an exact color match.

Comment: @Jet.B.Pope It's not about exact color match between screens. It's on the same screen. https://i.imgur.com/C0YAra4.png it's an SM-T510 Samsung Galaxy Tab A 10.1 (2019)

Comment: Can you try making that Container 0xff294151 and see if there's difference then?

Comment: @Ivo well yes, that seems to display the same. But that isn't the color my colorpicker in windows and paint.net is showing.

Comment: Looks like the problem might be Windows 11, not Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on web and fixed it by changing from canvaskit renderer to html renderer. More info: https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/renderers